# Clear undo buffer for PKCanvasView

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

I'm experimenting with Apple's PencilKit. Showing the `PKToolPicker` works well and I can draw into my canvas. However, I wondered whether and if so, how it is possible to clear the undo buffer.

Background: I'm allowing the user to flip through his drawings, but the undo buttons are still available on the iPad even if I assign a new drawing to the `PKCanvasView`. I would like to clear the undo buffer before I show one of the previous drawings.

I've tried to clear the parent view controller's undo buffer and the `PKCanvasView`'s undo buffer by calling

```
self.undoManager?.removeAllActions()
self.canvasView.undoManager?.removeAllActions()
```

to no avail.

Optionally, it would also be ok for me to just hide the undo/redo buttons from the `PKToolPicker` on the iPad. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same question.

Comment: Nope, no solution so far.